# Incorrect behaviour of .check() in z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

Consider a set of constraints F = [a + b > 10, a*a + b + 10 < 50].

When I run it using:

```
s = Solver()
s.add(F)
s.check()
```

I get `sat` solution.

If I run it with:

```
s = Solver()
s.check(F)
```

I get an `unknown` solution. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
F = [a + b > 10, a*a + b + 10 < 50]

s = Solver()
s.add(F)
print (s.check())
print (s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[b = 15, a = -4]
```

That looks good to me.

Let's try your second variant:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
F = [a + b > 10, a*a + b + 10 < 50]

s = Solver()
print (s.check(F))
print (s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[b = 7, a = 4]
```

That looks good to me too.

So, I don't know how you're getting the `unknown` answer. Maybe you have an old version of z3; or you've some other things in your program you're not telling us about.

The important thing to note, however, is that `s.add(F); s.check()` AND `s.check(F)` are *different* operations:

- `s.add(F); s.check()` means: Assert the constraints in `F`; check that they are satisfiable.
- `s.check(F)` means: Check that all the *other* constraints are satisfiable, *assuming* *F* is. In particular, it does *not* assert `F`. (This is important if you do further asserts/checks later on.)

So, in general these two different ways of using `check` are used for different purposes; and can yield different answers. But in the presence of no other assertions around, you'll get a solution for both, though of course the models might be different.

*Aside* One reason you can get `unknown` is in the presence of non-linear constraints. And your `a*a+b+10 < 50` is non-linear, since it does have a multiplication of a variable by itself. You can deal with that either by using a bit-vector instead of an `Int` (if applicable), or using the nonlinear-solver; which can still give you `unknown`, but might perform better. But just looking at your question as you asked it, z3 is just fine handling it.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is going on within `s.check(F)`, you can do the following:

```
from z3 import *
import inspect

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
F = [a + b > 10, a*a + b + 10 < 50]

s = Solver()
print (s.check(F))
print (s.model())

source_check = inspect.getsource(s.check)  
print(source_check)
```

The resulting output:

```
sat
[b = 10, a = 1]
    def check(self, *assumptions):
        """Check whether the assertions in the given solver plus the optional assumptions are consistent or not.

        >>> x = Int('x')
        >>> s = Solver()
        >>> s.check()
        sat
        >>> s.add(x > 0, x < 2)
        >>> s.check()
        sat
        >>> s.model().eval(x)
        1
        >>> s.add(x < 1)
        >>> s.check()
        unsat
        >>> s.reset()
        >>> s.add(2**x == 4)
        >>> s.check()
        unknown
        """
        s = BoolSort(self.ctx)
        assumptions = _get_args(assumptions)
        num = len(assumptions)
        _assumptions = (Ast * num)()
        for i in range(num):
            _assumptions[i] = s.cast(assumptions[i]).as_ast()
        r = Z3_solver_check_assumptions(self.ctx.ref(), self.solver, num, _assumptions)
        return CheckSatResult(r)
```

The semantics of *assumptions* vs. *assertions* are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180000/1911064) and [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1152). But if have to admit that they are not really clear to me yet.